# Server datetime vs Client datetime

Tags: c++, sql, networking, mfc

I am most likely missing some simple solution, but I have an executable (written in c++) where I use and/or save the current datetime into a SQLite or Sybase database (both executable an database are on the server) the issue that i am having is that I would like it to use the datetime from the server computer (where the database is at) instead of using the datetime on the client. Is there a way to have the database give the time from the computer where it is at or some other way to get the server time? Is this possible, or do I have ensure the clients will be the same time as server?

Right now I am just using a simple sql query:

```
Select dateTime('now'); //for SQLite
Select Now(*); //for Sybase
```

Edit: Sybase does already give you the server time correctly so I am only looking for the SQLite solution

Comment: You say that the executable is on the server, so isn't the client machine also the server? Or do you mean that the executable just happens to reside on the server, but it is run from a separate (client) machine?

Comment: In the problem cases the executable is on the server on a mapped drive and the clients runs a shortcut that point to that executable. So yes it just resides on the server and is run from a different machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only real solution is to keep all machines' time synchronized by using ntp or sntp.  Both easier and more accurate than any other solution, and all modern OS have standard provisions on board to sync with a time server.

You can either choose to sync on some external server, install one on a server at your place, and/or buy a dedicated device that acts as an ntp server for your network.  It all depends on whether you want the time to be correct in absolute terms (that will necessitate consulting some external time signal) or only among your machines.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the server time then the simplest method is to get it from the server, either by doing what you are doing now, or by adding another layer to your app, e.g. a web service which resides on the server and which sends the local machine time to the db. The benefit of this method is that if you change your business requirements to allow machines in other time zones to use your app, then the local time is unaffected.

Other than that you will have to ensure the machines are synched which is not always bulletproof, e.g. if you use an external time signal and it becomes unavailable.